# Drop/Create Table (SQL - Procedure)

Tags: sql, procedure

I'm trying to create a very simple procedure (with a simple code - I'm a beginner and I want to keep my code as simple as possible) which can Drop a table named "Table1" and Create a table named "Students" containing 3 columns: ID, Name, Mark

This is my code and it doesn't work at all:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Drop_Create
@Table1 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Students VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @Students + '('SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[Name] [NVARCHAR(50)] NOT NULL,[Mark] [INT])';
    SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS DROP TABLE [' + @Table1 + ']'
    PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC @SQL;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you intentionally using dynamic SQL? If the table names are static, ditch that approach. Otherwise:

Issue 1, Your if exists.. was totally wrong.

Issue 2, You overwrote @SQL without executing the first task

Issue 3, You had square brackets around [Varchar(50)]

Even as you have it now, it will break the second time you run it (it will try to create @Students again). I suspect you're confusing yourself with the logic somehow.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Drop_Create
@Table1 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Students VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Drop @table1
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + @Table1 + ''') AND type in (N''U'')) DROP TABLE [' + @Table1 + ']'
    PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC (@SQL);

    -- Create @Students
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @Students + '('
    SET @SQL = @SQL + '[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,[Mark] [INT])';

    PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC (@SQL);
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks a heap for your help. I wonder if there's any other way to write that the first line of Drop: 

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id ....

Comment: It's the "belt and bracers" way to be 100% sure it will work. Sometimes ugly is best. Did you need to use dynamic SQL? You never answered me on that.